# Start activity from ViewHolder onclick

Tags: android

I´m tryng to start a new activity when the user clicks on a RecycleView element . The problem is that only one field of object I want to pass to JSON is show in the row_item Layout and don´t know how to retrieve the other 3 object fields.

Here are the steps I´m following .

First I send a list of objects (Poliza) to the adapter .
Second I show only one field of the object (poliza) in the RecycleView .
Third  I want to start a new activity when the user clicks on the RecycleView item , sending a JSON of the object with the other object fields that are not show in the row_item .

Here is my adapter

```
public class PolizasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PolizasAdapter.PolizaViewHolder> {

    private List<Poliza> listapoliza = null;
    private Context context;

    public PolizasAdapter(  List<Poliza> listapoliza) {
        this.listapoliza = listapoliza;
    }

    public class PolizaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        TextView txtPoliza;

        public PolizaViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            //Agregamos un onclickListener
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            context = view.getContext();
            //Hacemos referencia a las vistas del rowitem
            txtPoliza = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_poliza);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Evento que que se genera cuando se da click
            TextView texto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_poliza);
            String str = texto.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(str);
            //Iniciamos actividad mostrando el detalle

             Intent intent = new Intent(context , DetalleActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("id_poliza",str);
            //Whats next ?
            //How to add the other 3 fields of my object to the putExtra


        }
    }

    @Override
    public PolizasAdapter.PolizaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Creamos una nueva vista
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
        PolizaViewHolder viewHolder = new PolizaViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

     @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PolizasAdapter.PolizaViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.txtPoliza.setText("Poliza : " + String.valueOf(listapoliza.get(position).getPoliza()));
    }

   )
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listapoliza.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: `context.startActivity(intent);`

Comment: you can pass the whole list to activity and retrieve the list in activity and filter the object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For starting the Activity you should do `context.startActivity(intent);`
As for the 3 JSON parameter you're talking about, i couldn't find any reference of them in your code (there's no reference to any JSON whatsoever). I guess you might be talking about a field from Poliza object, but i can't be sure.

Comment: Exactly those fields are from the object . I want to retrieve the object in the on click .

Comment: The correct place to bind the Poliza object to an action would be the onBindViewHolder, which bind the view to it's data element. Right now you're only setting the text of a field inside the ViewHolder, but you could create a method inside the ViewHolder which takes a Poliza object as a parameter and then hold a reference to it inside the ViewHolder, so that you could retrieve it in the onClick method.
Another option would that instead of holding a reference you could use a final variable and set the onClick as an annonymous class so that you could access that variable inside the loader method

Comment: Thanks Jonatan , looking into the BindViewHolder was the solution .

Answer (score 3):

Use Activity context

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,AnotherActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `view.context.startactivity(new Intent(view.context.this, NewActivity().class))`